# Quickly go to the end of "syntax highlighted" element

Tags: key-bindings, navigation, jumplist

I am using syntax highlighting to help with writing `LaTeX` documents in vim. My documents involve a lot of brackets, and it is easy to do a trivial mistake and end-up with something which doesn't compile; though it can be fixed, it wastes a lot of time.

**Question** : Is there any way to jump to the end/start of the highlighted pair? In the following picture `\left\{` is recognised as a partner for `\right\}`, how to go to anywhere near (start or end or middle) of `\right\}` if the cursor is on :

- `\left\{`
- somewhere between `\left\{` and `\right\}`

[image: pic]

Edit : As per comments -

```
+\sqrt{\frac{i}{2}} \sqrt{\frac{i-1}{2}} \left\{ e^{i t_{1} E_{i,i-1}} e^{i t_{2} E_{i-1,i}} - e^{i t_{2} E_{i,i-1}} e^{i t_{1} E_{i-1,i}} \right\} - \sqrt{\frac{i}{2}} \sqrt{\frac{i-2}{2}} \cancelto{0}{\left\{ e^{i t_{1} E_{i,i-1}} e^{i t_{2} E_{i-1,i-2}} - e^{i t_{2} E_{i,i-1}} e^{i t_{1} E_{i-1,i-2}} \right\}} \\
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! I think `matchit` (`:h matchit`) might work. It gives you the ability to jump between matching 'groups' with `%`. Besides, could you post your first image as text? It'd be more readable (and I could copy to test on it).

Comment: Seconded: [please dont post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Comment: @Biggybi Added the text in edit. I am trying with `matchit` and if I can make it work, will update here.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thank you. Will keep this in mind from now on!

Comment: Also, can someone point me to the correct terminology here? Should I call them partner tags?

Comment: @Nitin Vim's help for 'matchit' calls them 'matching groups', although 'partner tags' is pretty descriptive in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `matchit` plugin for this. It supports many languages, and seem to work great with LaTeX.

It allows you to use `%` to jump between matching tags.

To install it, you can simply add this line to your `vimrc` file:

```
packadd! matchit
```

Or instal from [the repo](https://github.com/adelarsq/vim-matchit) with your favourite plugin manager.

Comment: Thanks. I am a little confused : what's the role of `matchit` here? `%` seems to work whether or not I am using `matchit`. I disabled the `packadd! matchit` command from my `vimrc` and still `%` seems to work just fine!

Comment: Oh, well. Basically, it 'unlocks' more pairs. In `:h %` is a note about this :)

Comment: Yes @Nitin matchit allows a “pair” to be, for example, if/elseif/else/endif as opposes to just just brackets

Comment: Perfect! Thanks guys :)